# Can't grab QGesture events from a QTreeWidget anymore

Tags: c++, qt, gesture

This very simple program used to work perfectly when using Qt 5.6 on Android, it now fails with Qt 5.12. On Windows, it works with both versions.

It's very simple, just creating a helper to catch QGesture events and notify a specified class.

**gesture.h**:

```
#ifndef RMCWRAPPER_H
#define RMCWRAPPER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QPoint>

class QWidget;

class TapAndHoldWrapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TapAndHoldWrapper( QWidget* parent, QObject* receiver = NULL, const char* slot = NULL );
    ~TapAndHoldWrapper();

    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

signals:
    void requested( QPoint globalPos );

private:
    QWidget* m_parent;
};

#endif
```

**gesture.cpp**:

```
#include "gesture.h"

#include <QWidget>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QGestureEvent>

TapAndHoldWrapper::TapAndHoldWrapper( QWidget* parent, QObject* receiver, const char* slot ) : 
    QObject( parent ), m_parent( parent )
{
    m_parent->installEventFilter( this );
    m_parent->grabGesture( Qt::TapAndHoldGesture );

    if ( receiver && slot )
    {
        connect( this, SIGNAL(requested(QPoint)), receiver, slot );
    }
}

TapAndHoldWrapper::~TapAndHoldWrapper()
{

}

bool TapAndHoldWrapper::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if ( event->type() == QEvent::Gesture && obj == m_parent )
    {
        QGestureEvent *gestevent = static_cast<QGestureEvent *>(event);
        if (QGesture *gest = gestevent->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture))
        {
            if ( gest && gest->state() == Qt::GestureFinished )
            {
                QPoint globalPos = gest->hotSpot().toPoint();
                emit requested( globalPos );
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

**mainwidget.h**:

```
#ifndef MAINWIDGET_H
#define MAINWIDGET_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class TapAndHoldWrapper;

class MainWidget : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void showMenu( QPoint pt );

private:
    TapAndHoldWrapper* helper;
};

#endif
```

**mainwidget.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwidget.h"
#include "gesture.h"

#include <QScreen>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QTreeWidget* widget = new QTreeWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(widget);

    helper = new TapAndHoldWrapper( widget, this, SLOT(showMenu(QPoint)) );
}

void MainWidget::showMenu( QPoint pt )
{
    QMessageBox::information( this, "", "gesture detected" );
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwidget.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWidget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

`TapAndHoldWrapper` used to catch the event and make `MainWidget::showMenu` be invoked. It does not anymore. It works perfectly when the `QMainWindow`'s central widget is a `QLabel`, but it fails when it's a `QTreeWidget`.

The log reports this error (new in Qt 5.12):

```
    W/libqtbug_gesture.so(22735): QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method
    QTreeWidget::inputMethodQuery(Qt::InputMethodQuery,QVariant)
```

Is there anything special that needs to be done for `QTreeWidget` to work smartly with gestures on Android with Qt 5.12? Is there somthing special to be done with input methods? I tried to call `widget->setInputMethodHints( Qt::InputMethodHint::ImhNone );` but it did not help...

Comment: Submitted Qt bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73326

Answer (score 0):

As this is apparently a Qt bug, the only solution is to workround it. Tap and hold can be easily detected like below:

**gesture.h**:

```
#ifndef RMCWRAPPER_H
#define RMCWRAPPER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QTime>

class QWidget;

class TapAndHoldWrapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TapAndHoldWrapper( QWidget* parent, QObject* receiver = NULL, const char* slot = NULL );
    ~TapAndHoldWrapper();

    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

signals:
    void requested( QPoint globalPos );

private:
    QWidget* m_parent;
    QTime m_pressedAt;
    QPoint m_pressedPos;
};

#endif
```

**gesture.cpp**:

```
#include "gesture.h"

#include <QWidget>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QGestureEvent>
#include <QAbstractScrollArea>

#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK( 5, 12, 0 )
// handle this manually, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73326
#define HANDLE_TAP_AND_HOLD_MANUALLY
#endif

TapAndHoldWrapper::TapAndHoldWrapper( QWidget* parent, QObject* receiver, const char* slot ) : 
    QObject( parent ), 
    m_parent( parent )
{
    // optional in Qt 5.6. Required in Qt 5.12
    QAbstractScrollArea* area = dynamic_cast< QAbstractScrollArea* >( m_parent );
    if ( area )
        m_parent = area->viewport();

    m_parent->installEventFilter( this );

#ifndef HANDLE_TAP_AND_HOLD_MANUALLY
    m_parent->grabGesture( Qt::TapAndHoldGesture );
#endif

    if ( receiver && slot )
    {
        connect( this, SIGNAL(requested(QPoint)), receiver, slot );
    }
}

TapAndHoldWrapper::~TapAndHoldWrapper()
{

}

bool TapAndHoldWrapper::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
#ifdef HANDLE_TAP_AND_HOLD_MANUALLY
    if ( event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress && obj == m_parent )
    {
        QMouseEvent* mouseEvent = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>( event );
        if ( mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
        {
            m_pressedAt = QTime::currentTime();
            m_pressedPos = mouseEvent->globalPos();
        }
    }
    else if ( event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease && obj == m_parent )
    {
        QMouseEvent* mouseEvent = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent*>( event );
        if ( mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
        {
            int elapsed = m_pressedAt.msecsTo( QTime::currentTime() );
            if ( elapsed >= 500 )
            {
                if ( std::abs( m_pressedPos.x() - mouseEvent->globalPos().x() ) < 10 &&
                     std::abs( m_pressedPos.y() - mouseEvent->globalPos().y() ) < 10 )
                {
                    emit requested( mouseEvent->globalPos() );
                }
                // else, mouse moved too much, it's not a tap and 
            }
        }
    }
#else
    if ( event->type() == QEvent::Gesture && obj == m_parent )
    {
        QGestureEvent *gestevent = static_cast<QGestureEvent *>(event);
        if (QGesture *gest = gestevent->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture))
        {
            if ( gest && gest->state() == Qt::GestureFinished )
            {
                QPoint globalPos = gest->hotSpot().toPoint();
                emit requested( globalPos );
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
#endif

    // standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Note that event filter must be installed on viewport rather than widget itself.